# visual illusion / unidentifed "floating" object

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There seems to be an "underscore" on the top left corner of the slideshow (Yootheme/Widgetkit plugin) but there is none in the source. Yet it moves in and out with each frame !

http://www.la-belle-equipe.org/

Can you see it ? Has anybody an idea about what it is ? I've been thoroughly inspecting each element for days (weeks !) and could not find anything relevant.

Comment: I can't see it in either Chrome or IE. Please show a screen grab.

Comment: Indeed. Problem solved by RickCigarette below. Isn't there some "solved" tag or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your culprit:

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text:before {
color: #666;
content: '—2014'; <- this line inserts the dash before each caption.
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 7px;
}
```

You gotta remove that line from the css or overwrite it with `.wp-caption .wp-caption-text:before { content: '' }` included after that rule

Comment: +1 - yup, that would do it, and that character wouldn't be present in the source.

Comment: Be blessed !! Thank you so much. Did you use any particular tool or is it only "experience speaking" ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools. You have to inspect that paragraph and you can see all the CSS properties on it. Since you can't find it in the markup it must have been a `content:` property

Comment: Fine. Using "CDT" too. Simply did not know about "content" property !!  Thanks again. Have a nice day.